# How to skip between lines while parsing a text file in java

Tags: java, parsing, text-files

I am writing a compiler program to read a text file. Some of the commands in the text file will tell me to skip back to a certain line in the text file and read from there. As things are, this code I have reads one line at a time until the end of the document. Is there anyway to have a parser skip back or forward to a certain line in the text file? Let us say for example I am currently on line 8 and the instruction is to go back and read line 4?

Here is my code for parsing the file.

```
try {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("compilers.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    String strLine;

    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null && checker == false) {
        // rest of code in here
    }
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: why don't you read all lines, save them in a list (each line one entry) and do your work than?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a `Map`

```
HashMap<Integer, String>
```

Key is your line number and value is your line. So you can get the line by line number when you required.

```
Map<Integer, String> lineMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
int i = 1;
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null && !checker) {
    lineMap.put(i, strLine);
    // do what you want
    // if you are in line 8 (i=8)
    // get my line 4 (lineMap.get(4))
    i++;
}
```

Comment: A totally miss use of a hashMap! ArayList would be the correct Collection

Answer (score 2):

There is the Stream `mark()` and `reset()` function,
but these can fail when using `BufferedStream`s. Better you
read the whole file into an `ArrayList`, each line one entry.

Example for ArrayList:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(strLine);
}

// later get line by:
// first line has index 0    
String line = lines.get(8);
```

Comment: thanks for your time in answering, I have decided to go for the hashmap though :)

Comment: You shoul dnot use a HashMap in that scenarion, an ArrayList is the go. Hashmaps are for keys like names, etc. but nor for an ordered sequence form 0 to N-1.